# Gradual transition of an interrupted CSS keyframes :hover animation

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations, css-transforms

My animation uses keyframes, starts on hover and has a long duration.
When I move the mouse out while the animation is still running it stops instantly.
I need the **interrupted** animation returns to it's original values gradually. (Like 'transform' does).

```
@keyframes KF_Problem { 100% {transform:scale(2);} }
.Problem:hover { animation:KF_Problem 3s; }
.Problem       { transform:scale(1); transition:3s;}

.All_OK:hover  { transform:scale(2); transition:3s;}
.All_OK        { transform:scale(1); transition:3s;}
```

1) How can I do that?

2) Why does Firefox "do the work" automatically and all other browsers don't?

Just try the code in http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_default with Firefox and with all other modern browsers to see the difference...

Comment: Do you need to be using keyframes? If not, then jut put your `transform:scale(1.5)` in your hover declaration. If you do need the keyframes, then I would put `animation: KF_Problem 3s 1 both;` and `animation-direction: reverse` on the non-hover declaration. I don't know if that will work or not, though.

Comment: No, I need to use keyframes. The code is just a simplified example.